# edittext making the app crashing when a text is introduced instead of a number

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, android-edittext

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="my_array">

    <item>rome 999 3 4 5 7 9 11 17</item>

</string-array>
```

which I use to initialize a sqlite table with this structure:

```
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SCHEDULE = "schedule";
}
```

Here is the code where I parse the values and put them in the table

```
for (String item : myArray){
        String[] split = item.split("\\s+");

        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, split[0]);
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, split[1]);
        String schedule="";

        String[] stringArray = item.split("\\s+");
        int length = stringArray.length;

        for (int i = 2; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if(schedule.trim().length()>0){
                schedule += split[i]+" ";
            }else{
                schedule = split[i];
            }
        }


        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SCHEDULE, schedule);
        db.insert(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
```

Now, after that I make an sqlite request on it like:

```
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  
            projection,                               
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE+" = " + string ,                              
            null,                            
            null,                                     
            null,                                   
            sortOrder                                 
    );
```

I use the cursor to create a new edittext in this way:

```
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
            result = result + cursor.getString(iRow) + " " + cursor.getString(iName) +
                    " " + cursor.getString(iSchedule) +
                    "\n";
        }
TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textview.setText(result);
        RelativeLayout myLayout;
        myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());
        myLayout.addView(textview, params);
```

However, if I change the xml file in and I introduce a text in the second element, for example like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="my_array">

    <item>rome line1 3 4 5 7 9 11 17</item>

</string-array>
```

if I repeat things and I make an sqlite request by looking for the text `line1` , the app crashes. i.e. that in the code above the sqlite is only expecting a number and not a text. I don't understand the origin of this behavior from such a code. Also, how can I make it working with text as well?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are actually parsing the string and writing it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you expect Rome to show up as the title instead of 999. If that is the case then the easiest fix would be to change your string-array to read as

`<item>999 Rome 3 4 5 7 9 11 17</item>`